# Why is the Base-emitter ON voltage as high as 2V in the BJT datasheet?

Tags: analog, bjt, components, datasheet, semiconductors

Below is a snippet from a [BJT datasheet](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/308/BD243B_D-2310128.pdf). Why is the Base-emitter ON volatge mentioned as 2V?
The Base emitter voltage should be 0.7V when the BJT conducts.

[image]

Comment: I don’t know for certain but I suspect that some of these datasheet values are based on production testing, in other words any transistor that has a Vbe greater than 2V under these test conditions is rejected; in reality 99.9% of parts may have a Vbe of around 700-800mV

Answer (score 7):

The 0.7V is a typical rough estimate value for a typical generic small signal transistor with few milliamps of base current. It can be used as a simple mental model in general.

What you have is not a general case. You have a power transistor capable of switching 6A, and the 2V value is rated at very large base current of 1A which is required to saturate the transistor enough to drive 6A collector current.

Answer (score 7):

Your BJT datasheet plots always shows nominal and the tables show Max.

I added what to expect in Red to interpolate for worst case MAX devices due to process variances @ 25'C

These are exceptionally high base currents as the linear current gain is very low (15 MIN) and Vce saturated current gain is "defined" at hFE=10 or Ic/Ib=10.

These are the standard ways to define transistors.

They do not guarantee the VbeMAX at Ic = 1.0A for example.

- You must extrapolate Rce from the worst case Vce(sat)/Ic=Rce(sat) by calculations or linear regression on plots.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That figure requires a few 100 mA of base current. If the base resistance is a few Ohms, one ends up at substantially higher than 0.7 V.